# Is there a word to describe the situation where you call someone and hang up so they call you back?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word to describe the situation where you call someone and hang up so they call you back? The purpose of this is usually so that they get the calling charges.

I was thinking it's kind of like 'poking' or 'tagging' them? Like a 'poke/tag call'.

**Answer:**

I voted on Tim Lewis' answer as it was the most interesting and it also suggested the answer which makes the most sense. Because we don't have a word for this in the English language, the word *Ping* can now be used as follows:

Ping *(verb)*: the act of calling someone and then hanging up with the intent of having them call back.

**Addendum:** Based on [this article](http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,298514,00.html) Wayne Werner linked to in a below comment, the practice is known as *beeping*. This article lays out the reasons for beeping and the social protocol around it.

Comment: People I know say *ring me* (as opposed to *call me*) in this situation, but I don't know how standard that is, as some people use *ring* as a synonym for *call*.

Comment: I don't know of a specific word or phrase for this.

Comment: My friends say, "Give me a missed call".

Comment: I always just say "ringback". e.g. I had no credit, so I ringbacked him.

Comment: This practice is so popular in certain regions of Africa that they actually built an entire side-network that rings are shunted to because they would eat up the normal network bandwidth. I saw an article on it a few years back, but they might have a term for the practice.

Comment: @Wayne That's really interesting,  if you find that article post it!

Comment: @ChrisM: not sure if this is the article I read, but it has a lot of the same information [FoxNews](http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,298514,00.html). Miskin, flashing, and bipage are among the terms they use.

Comment: @Wayne Very relevant and interesting article! They defined the term as 'beeping', perhaps that is the norm?

Comment: @tenfour: In India, the term is indeed "missed call" and everyone understands it :)

Comment: @JoseK A *missed call* describes the situation where someone calls you and you don't answer. The *ping* or *beep* is a subset of missed calls where the intent is to create a missed call so they call you back. *Missed call* itself doesn't describe the situation by the OP.

Comment: @ChrisM: Agreed, but in India, we commonly say, `Give me a missed call` for precisely this sort of pinging.

Comment: @Josek Oh I see, that's interesting. It sounds so improper in English haha

Comment: what if the purpose is not getting a callback? I sometimes do this to imply something as the receiver expects (eg: "I've arrived outside your apartment, come on out") and since they know what it is about already, there is no need to talk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently in Czech its called "Prozvonit" which in English is close to "ping" "pinging". Also I've heard people call it "prank" "pranking".

Comment: "Pranking" is usually meant to imply a practical joke.

Comment: "Prozvonit" has the connotation of "ring through" or "ring for"... not sure this overtone would be understandable in English, but "ping" is the closest word we have for it.

Comment: I like pinging.

Comment: Many of my business-jargon-using friends will indeed ask me to "ping them", but it has a different meaning (at least when they use it, and its employment is ubiquitous): it means *to contact them*, suggesting that they will answer.

Comment: I feel that saying 'ping me' (instead of 'ring my phone and I'll call you back') would make sense and would be a good word except that if I said it to my friends now, no one would actually understand my meaning. Perhaps the meaning of 'ping' should be officially established to include this definion.

Answer (score 8):

My friend regularly uses the expression *to ring **one's phone***.

Ex: "Ring my phone when you're over the bridge," the implication being that he won't answer because I'm calling his phone, rather than calling him.

I would note that this is distinct from onomatomaniak's comment-answer *to ring **someone***, which is a British English colloquialism for calling someone.

Comment: I've heard this one (and probably used it) myself.

Comment: One could also say "ring my number"

Comment: @AndrewVit I suppose so! It has (nearly) the same semantic value.

Comment: I feel that of all the proposals so far 'ring my phone' makes the most sense, however it's a phrase and not a word. Saying 'ring me' has the same meaning as 'call me'. Even still, however, I feel most people would interpret 'ring my phone' as 'call me and I'll answer' not 'call me and I'll not pick up and I will call you back'.

Answer (score 5):

The term I have always used is [drop call](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drop%20call).

If you drop call someone you hope they'll call you back, but it can make the recipient a bit annoyed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a form of what services like [this one](http://www.kallback.com/) call a *trigger*.

The situation you're describing triggers a manual response rather than an automated one:

> A customer simply dials our U.S. "trigger number", lets it ring once
>   and hangs up before it answers. Within seconds, our computer rings
>   back the caller.

Answer (score 3):

I've only known one word for it: Callback

I first heard this in the BBS days, where it provides enhanced security. Also good when a friend calls me from the UK on his mobile (I'm from Los Angeles and in Vermont).
More here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28telecommunications%29

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's easier to say it in [another language](http://betterthanenglish.com/prozvonit-czech/).

And, there might not exist a word in English that fits the situation, according to [this article](http://matadornetwork.com/abroad/20-awesomely-untranslatable-words-from-around-the-world/).

Perhaps we could borrow the word *prozvonit* from the Czech language.

Comment: Honestly, that word is too long for the suggested definition. If a word was to be adopted it would most likely be much shorter. Perhaps a derivation of that Czech word, though I can't think of any.

It is more likely that an existing English word with a similar meaning will be modified to include this new definition.

Comment: @ChrisM Agree. Shall we take the initiative :)

Comment: Li Yifeng Let's do this. Watch out blogs, Facebook statuses, and texts everywhere! (so this comment is constructive... the previously mentioned are all valid methods of promoting a new word. Use them all to spread the new definition of 'Ping'!)

Comment: @ChrisM 'Ping' totally rules!

Comment: In Italian they say give me a "squillo" (i.e. a ring), makes it easy to derive a squeal. "Give me a squeal when you get back home from the party."

Answer (score 1):

Ping, touch, signal, RSVP, hint...

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this referred to as "Phone Tag". Regardless of your intent, if your initial call doesn't succeed and you are called back, you are playing phone tag.

Comment: I had this word in mind actually but I disregarded it as I thought that the assumed intent of "phone tag" (trying to actually contact the person) was part of the definition.

[Here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telephone+tag) and [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phone_tag) are definitions of phone tag. These definitions include the intent to contact the other party.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, certainly in the North-East, it is known as a ***"one-ringer"***.

It's essential where you let the phone ring once, giving the person you are calling little chance of answering.

They either hear the phone or see the missed call and call you back.

> I've got no credit on my mobile so I'll give him a one-ringer and he'll call me back.

Answer (score 0):

This expression does not only exist in Czech, but in Spanish as well.

It's very usual among teenagers in Spain to "give a touch" (dar un toque)

I had this nagging feeling talking with a british friend looking for a word to describe this and ended up saying "I will touch your phone so you know when to call me back"

The poor guy answered "how are you going to touch my phone? you will be in the street."

Later I asked him and we decided the best translation would be "I will ring you"
as at least that conveys the meaning of an unfinished phone call.

Comment: In Spanish you also hear it called simple "una perdida" as in "dame una perdida" (give me a lost/missed call).

Answer (score 0):

One way of describing this is "reversing the charges."

Comment: To me in the UK this would imply [a specific type of call](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9596/~/how-do-i-make-a-reverse-charge-call%3F) that goes through the operator.

Answer (score -1):

A Nepali friend of mine says *give me a knock*.